# Check if a function exists in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a script that grades homework written in OCaml. What I have our two files, `homework.ml` and `testRunner.ml`. The `homework.ml` has functions implemented by the student with names as required by the homework. For eg. say the student was asked to implement a function that calculates the square of a number with function name `square`. The student can skip writing the function if he does not know the answer.

My `testRunner.ml` can run the functions from `homework.ml` but it fails if the student does **not** have the said function implemented complaining about `Unbound value square` in this case.

Is there a way in OCaml to check if a function exists before making a call to it? I tried to wrap the function call in a `try...with` but turns out this still does not work.

```
print_string "my_function [] 5 = "; 
try 
  print_endline (string_of_int (my_function [] 5)); (* This fails because the student did not write the my_function function *)
with _ -> print_string "Error";;
```

Apologies if this has already been asked somewhere, I could not find it.

Comment: Can you not just have a default implementation that raises an exception instead? i.e. `let square a b = failwith "not implemented"`

Comment: Hey @glennsl I am new to OCaml so I'll try to phrase what I understand from your comment. if I understand correctly there needs to be a default implementation in the testRunner.ml file with the same name as the function. But how does OCaml know that this is the default implementation and use it as a backup only?

Comment: I was thinking the default implementation would be in `homework.ml`, but you could have it in `testRunner.ml` as well. Let me elaborate in a proper answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot tinker with the `homework.ml` so I need to keep everything in the `testRunner.ml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in OCaml are static, meaning function names must refer to specific implementations at compile-time.

The simplest solution would therefore be to provide the student with a `homework.ml` file that provides default implementations for every function that needs to be implemented. This could also include descriptions of the assignments as comments associated with each function. For example:

```
(* (Optional) Implement a function [square] which squares the integer [x] *)
let square x =
  failwith "not implemented"
```

But you can also provide default implementations in `testRunner.ml` and include the contents of `homework.ml` after them. If `square` is not defined there it will then fall back to the earlier defined default implementation, and if it is defined the student's implementation will shadow the default. For sandboxing purposes it's also a good idea to do this in a submodule:

```
module H = struct
  let square _ =
    failwith "not implemented"

  include Homework (* This will essentially include the contents of homework.ml at this point *)
end

let () =
  print_string "square 5 = "; 

  try 
    print_endline (string_of_int (H.square 5))
  with
    _ -> print_string "Error"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. I do need to read up on how to use and manage submodules but this is exactly what I was looking for (for now at least)! Thank you for your time.